# celery throws unicodedecodeerror when try to start

Tags: celery

I want to run example code(tasks.py) from official tutorial:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
@app.task
def add(x, y): return x + y
```

I used command "celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info" as shown in the tutorial.
But, when I execute this command python throws UnicodeDecodeError:

```
C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\Scripts>celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\Scripts\celery-script.py", line 9, in <mod
ule>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.8', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", lin
e 30, in main
    main()
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", l
ine 80, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", l
ine 746, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", lin
e 308, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", l
ine 738, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", l
ine 692, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", l
ine 175, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", lin
e 271, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", l
ine 195, in run
    hostname = self.simple_format(default_nodename(hostname))
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", lin
e 569, in simple_format
    return self._simple_format(s, socket.gethostname(), **extra)
  File "C:\kaznmu\virtualenvs\example\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", lin
e 574, in _simple_format
    name, _, domain = host.partition('.')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 5: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

- I tried reinstall all python libraries and use different versions, but this doesn't help. How can I run celery?
- I use Windows7 and Python2.7
- Official tutorial here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps

Answer (score 1):

Problem is russian characters in pc name. Solved by renaming pc name.